# Mixtures and solutions

Tags: arithmetic

Suppose we have two solutions of sulphuric acid in water. The first is 40% strong and second is 60% strong. We mix the two solutions, add 5 kg of pure water and obtain a 20% solution. If instead of adding 5 kg of pure water, we were to add 5 kg of an 80% solution, we would get a 70% solution. How much of the 40% solution and 60% solution do we have?

a) 2 kg : 1 kg  b) 1kg : 2 kg   c) 2 kg : 3 kg  d) 3 kg : 1kg

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. In particular, **can you form the given conditions into equations?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this from a speed test, you can manage with only one equation,
*as all the ratios in the choices are different*

Let the ratio of $40\%:60\%$ solutions be $1:k$, then

$\dfrac{0.4 + 0.6k}{1+k+5} = 0.2,\;$ which yields $k=2,\; i.e. 1\; kg:\;2\; kg$

A double check just for your satisfaction, plugging into the second equation:

$\dfrac{0.4*1 + 0.6*2 + 0.8*5}{1+2+5} = 0.7$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If the quantity of the solutions be $10x,10y$ KG respectively,

$$\dfrac{10x\cdot40\%+10y\cdot60\%}{10x+10y+5}=20\%$$

Similarly form another equation in $x,y$ from the second condition.

Now solve the two simultaneous linear equations in $x,y$

Comment: @trueblueanil,Thanks for your observation.